# VSCode Missing settings in settings.json file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can access the (JSON) file by simply:

- Open the command palette (either with <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
- Type "open settings"
- And then choose Open Settings (JSON)

The thing is that when i open those settings all the options presented are these:

```
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",    
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "------------",   
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",    
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
```

Nothing more, I want to change my option through the (JSON) settings.
I even installed the VIM extension and I would love to be able to customize it in the (JSON) file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's empty by default. But as you continue using the UI and installing extensions, etc...those extensions will automatically update your settings[.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rU13Qbvu_g8) json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`settings.json` is empty by default. It only contains settings that you've modified.

You can show the full list of JSON settings using Ctrl+Shift+P -> `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)`. Or just modify them from the GUI.

Comment: Humm, thanks for the help:) But just one more question, as I said I installed Vim, but the settings of that extension are not in that JSON file. In the tutorials I see all the Vim Settings are in a JSON file, wich I find a lot better to use.

Comment: So I actually found the solution. It's kinda simple, open the Settings (UI), go to `User` -> `Workbench` -> `Settings Editor` and then changing the `Editor` to JSON. That way the `Default.Settings.JSON` will contain all the settings, even for VIM or other extensions I think:)

Answer (score 0):

Does the json file not just override what is the default setting? so anything you put in there becomes the new default?
(Also, settings can be for a project workspace or global, so is that file in your project?)

Comment: Yhea, I think there is a space of settings that control the default and then a group of settings that override the default but of course don't delete it.